# How can Two-way Data Binding leads to infinite loops?

Tags: android, android-databinding, two-way-binding

I'm learning Data Binding by reading up on the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding). Everything makes sense expect the possible infinite loops in the two-way binding. As per the official docs on [two-way binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way):

> Be careful not to introduce infinite loops when using two-way data binding. When the user changes an attribute, the method annotated using @InverseBindingAdapter is called, and the value is assigned to the backing property. This, in turn, would call the method annotated using @BindingAdapter, which would trigger another call to the method annotated using @InverseBindingAdapter, and so on.

I understand first part of the statement that the method annotate with `@InverseBindingAdapter` will be called if the attribute is changed and new value is assigned to the backing property.

But what I don't understand is why  `@InverseBindingAdapter` method is called *again* when `@BindingAdapter` method is called in this process and how it leads to infinite loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better late than never I guess :) The reason why an infinite loop can happen is `InverseBindingAdapter` is a basically an observer for changes. So when a user changed something the `onChanged` observer in InverseBindingAdapter is triggered and executes some logic. So then `BindingAdapter` also reacts to the change in the field and updates value again so the change listener in `InverseBindingAdapter` is triggered again and not we are in a loop.

So here is some visual for that

1. User -> Types in their name "Joe"
2. InverseBindingAdapter -> triggered by the update
3. ObservableField/LiveData -> also updated with 2 way binding and now contains value "Joe"
4. As ObservableField/LiveData was updated BindingAdapter is triggered to set the new value into the filed.
5. InverseBindingAdapter -> detected another change in the field and got triggered.
6. step 3, 4, 5 on repeat....

Check my [article on Medium](https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-data-binding-binding-to-livedata-one-and-two-way-binding-dae1cd68530f) on advanced DataBinding it actually describes this case with the ViewPager and 2 way binding example. (Yes, shameless self-plug disclaimer)

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be resolved by checking the old and new values before setting the new value to the target view.

Example:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun setText(editText: EditText, value: Int) {
    val newVal = if (value == 0) "" else value.toString()
    val oldVal = editText.text.toString()
    if (oldVal == newVal) {
        return
    }
    editText.setText(newVal)
    if (newVal.isNotEmpty()) {
        editText.setSelection(newVal.length)
    }
}
```